# How do I turn on calculator in spotlight without enabling conversions?

Tags: macos, spotlight

In Yosemite spotlight sends all requests to multiple third parties depending on your settings.  I've disabled all of these options, leaving "Calculator, System Preferences and Applications" out of principle. Disabling conversions however, seems to have disabled the calculator too.

My question is how can I enable the calculator without enabling conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Yosemite. Disabling Conversions shouldn't disable the calculator entirely, but it does. You can provide feedback and file a bug report Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html
- https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Thanks.  Those are useful links, I've submitted a bug report and feedback.  I'll leave this question open on the offchance that someone has a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences > Spotlight > untick then re-tick the "Calculator".

Try it now it should work.